# Using cURL to findout where website redirects?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get server redirect url. I have tried

```
    function http_head_curl($url,$timeout=10)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout); // in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cURL exception: ".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch));
    }
    return trim($res);
}


echo http_head_curl("http://www.site.com",$timeout=10);
```

Result is;

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Sun, 12 May 2013 23:34:22 GMT
>   Server: LiteSpeed Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.23
>   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=0d4b28dd02bd3d8413c92f71253e8b31; path=/;
>   HttpOnly X-Pingback: http://site.com/xmlrpc.php Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=UTF-8  Location: http://site.com/ HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Sun, 12 May 2013 23:34:23 GMT Server: LiteSpeed  Connection:
>   close  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.23 Set-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=630ed27f107c07d25ee6dbfcb02e8dec; path=/;  HttpOnly
>   X-Pingback: http://site.com/xmlrpc.php Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8

It shows almost all header information, but not showing where it redirects. How do I get the redirected page url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `Location` header.

```
$headers = array();
$lines = explode("\n", http_head_curl('http://www.site.com', $timeout = 10));

list($protocol, $statusCode, $statusMsg) = explode(' ', array_shift($lines), 3);

foreach($lines as $line){
  $line = explode(':', $line, 2);
  $headers[trim($line[0])] = isset($line[1]) ? trim($line[1]) : '';
}

// 3xx = redirect    
if(floor($statusCode / 100) === 3)
  print $headers['Location'];
```

Comment: If $statuscode is returned as a string in the array, you could just use: if($statusCode[0] == 3)

Comment: Yeah, I actually had that in the previous edit, but it felt ugly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$response_header = substr($response, 0, $info['header_size']);
$response_header = parseHeaders($response_header, 'Status');
$content = substr(response, $info['header_size']);
$url_redirect = (isset($response_header['Location'])) ? $response_header['Location'] : null;
var_dump($url_redirect);

/*
* or you can use http://php.net/http-parse-headers, 
* but then need to install http://php.net/manual/en/book.http.php
*/
function parseHeaders($headers, $request_line)
{
    $results = array();
    $lines = array_filter(explode("\r\n", $headers));
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $name_value = explode(':', $line, 2);
        if (isset($name_value[1])) {
            $name = $name_value[0];
            $value = $name_value[1];
        } else {
            $name = $request_line;
            $value = $name_value[0];
        }
        $results[$name] = trim($value);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After your CURL request is done, use [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) with the CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL option. Done.

Compared to the other (complicated) answers, this will provide you the full URL that your request "ended up on".